# Find where a value would lie in a range

Tags: r

I have a data frame as such

```
"X1"    "X2"    "X3"    "X4"    "X5"    "X6"    "X7"    "X8"    "X9"    "X10"   "X11"   "X12"   "X13"   "X14"   "X15"   "X16"   "X17"   "X18"   "X19"   "X20"   "X21"   "X22"   "X23"   "X24"
    13062   145 9   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    586717  66068   18713   7105    3188    1506    750 460 251 141 81  41  39  14  12  6   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
    55893   1371    155 43  9   3   3   2   0   2   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    63123   2573    266 35  10  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    14258   63  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    751302  43884   6109    1280    368 123 36  18  6   0   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    45018   1017    89  10  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    182932  6581    941 238 73  43  20  9   6   8   2   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
    23741   356 4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    4391    15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    20201   546 75  17  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    48193   943 50  9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    11284   89  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    4819    48  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I am finding the mean for each row

`df$mean=apply(df,1,mean)`

```
"X1"    "X2"    "X3"    "X4"    "X5"    "X6"    "X7"    "X8"    "X9"    "X10"   "X11"   "X12"   "X13"   "X14"   "X15"   "X16"   "X17"   "X18"   "X19"   "X20"   "X21"   "X22"   "X23"   "X24"   "mean"
    13062   145 9   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   550.75
    586717  66068   18713   7105    3188    1506    750 460 251 141 81  41  39  14  12  6   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   28545.5833333333
    55893   1371    155 43  9   3   3   2   0   2   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2395.16666666667
    63123   2573    266 35  10  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2750.54166666667
    14258   63  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   596.875
    751302  43884   6109    1280    368 123 36  18  6   0   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   33463.7083333333
    45018   1017    89  10  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1922.5
    182932  6581    941 238 73  43  20  9   6   8   2   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7952.375
    23741   356 4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1004.20833333333
    4391    15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   183.583333333333
    20201   546 75  17  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   868.333333333333
    48193   943 50  9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2049.79166666667
    11284   89  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   473.916666666667
    4819    48  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   202.875
```

I want to figure out in the range of columns 1 to 24 where the mean would lie.

For example:

If I have x values as 1,2,3,4 and y as 10,20,30,40 . If I were to find value corresponding to 15 in x I would get 1.5 .Here I wish to find out where the mean would lie which could give me a floating point number specifying it lies at column e.g 1.5 .

**Update :**

Sample Data

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 mean
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 55
```

Here mean lies at 5.5 . How can I calculate something similar for the table above.

It can be assumed that the values in each row are sorted.

Comment: slight remark: it's "better" to use `rowMeans` to find the mean of each row in term of speed/conciseness.

Comment: rowMeans is better. Will remember.

Comment: Can you show your desired output for the data provided, as can't understand the question

Comment: and if the mean lies in-between several columns?

Comment: I suggest to rearrange your data first. For example the names of your dataframe aren't just names, but also data you are using. Read about [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-read.table(text="X1    X2   X3    X4    X5  X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19   X20   X21   X22   X23   X24
        13062   145 9   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       586717  66068   18713   7105    3188    1506    750 460 251 141 81  41  39  14  12  6   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
       55893   1371    155 43  9   3   3   2   0   2   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       63123   2573    266 35  10  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       14258   63  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       751302  43884   6109    1280    368 123 36  18  6   0   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       45018   1017    89  10  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       182932  6581    941 238 73  43  20  9   6   8   2   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
       23741   356 4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       4391    15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       20201   546 75  17  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       48193   943 50  9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       11284   89  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       4819    48  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0",header=T)

df$mean<-rowMeans(df)

n<-ncol(x)
apply(df,1,function(x) (max(which(x[n]<x[-n]))+min(which(x[n]>x[-n])))/2)

[1] 1.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
```